# iterating row by row over pandas dataframe with the possibility to jump back

Tags: python, pandas, iterator

I know that `pandas.DataFrame.iterrows` allows to iterate through a DataFrame row by row. Is it possible to jump back in the iteration?

For instance, I have a list of ten items. The iteration cursor is at #8. And for some reason i want to jump back to e.g. #5 and go on from there.

(how) can I do this?

I already tried to search for similar questions, but unfortunately to no avail.

Comment: You'd be better off using `df.iloc` as this is integer based rather than label based as your index values may not be 0 based int64, so something like `for i in range(len(df)): #doSomething with df.iloc[i]`

Comment: yes, that was what i was looking for. seems to be a bit slow, but anyway does the job.

Comment: It'll be slow because iterating row-wise is slow, generally it should be avoided

Comment: makes sense. but if you need to do some sort of checking which goes beyond "lines", e.g., detecting streaks over rows, i think it can't be avoided? if you have any pointers on how to do such things without iterating line-by-line i'd be grateful. thx

Comment: You'll have to flesh that out more and post it as a new question, basically one can perform some inter-row comparison using `shift()` or `rolling_apply` or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `iloc` which is integer based indexing to do the index selection, this is because your index may not be 0 based int64 but it will still work, example:

```
In [103]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(10)}, index = list('abcdefghij'))
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i != 0 and i % 5 == 0:
        print(df.iloc[i-3])
    else:
        print(df.iloc[i])
a    0
Name: a, dtype: int32
a    1
Name: b, dtype: int32
a    2
Name: c, dtype: int32
a    3
Name: d, dtype: int32
a    4
Name: e, dtype: int32
a    2
Name: c, dtype: int32
a    6
Name: g, dtype: int32
a    7
Name: h, dtype: int32
a    8
Name: i, dtype: int32
a    9
Name: j, dtype: int32
```